# Google Storage: Invalid Unicode path encountered

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload some files to GCS and i get this:

```
Building synchronization state...
Caught non-retryable exception while listing file:///media/Respaldo: CommandExce                       ption: Invalid Unicode path encountered
(u'/media/Respaldo/Documentos/Trabajo/Traducciones/Servicio
Preventivo Semanal Hs Rev3 - Ingl\xe9s.doc'). gsutil cannot
proceed with such files present. Please remove or rename this file and
try again. NOTE: the path printed above replaces the problematic
characters with a hex-encoded printable representation. For more
details (including how to convert to a gsutil-compatible encoding) see
`gsutil help encoding`.
```

But when i run:

```
convmv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 -r --replace /media/Respaldo
```

And says all the non English files are already UTF-8. How should I proceed?

Edit: example of convmv output:

```
Skipping, already UTF-8: /media/Respaldo/Multimedia/Mis ImÃ¡genes/NOKIA/Memoria/Videoclips/VÃ­deo004.3gp
Skipping, already UTF-8: /media/Respaldo/Multimedia/Mis ImÃ¡genes/NOKIA/Memoria/Videoclips/VÃ­deo009.3gp
Skipping, already UTF-8: /media/Respaldo/Multimedia/Mis ImÃ¡genes/NOKIA/Memoria/Videoclips/VÃ­deo00133.3gp
Skipping, already UTF-8: /media/Respaldo/Multimedia/Mis ImÃ¡genes/NOKIA/Memoria/Videoclips/VÃ­deo023.3gp
Skipping, already UTF-8: /media/Respaldo/Multimedia/Mis ImÃ¡genes/NOKIA/Memoria/Videoclips/VÃ­deo026.3gp
```

Comment: Are you certain that source file has encoding ISO-8859-1? Is it possible it's using a different encoding, so that convmv command doesn't find it?

Comment: `e9` is extended ascii 233, which is `é`, which is part of ISO-8859-1. Can you paste the exact output of convmv?

Comment: Sure, added an example output. Thanks!

Comment: @jterrace could you find something?

Comment: Can you post the output of running the `locale` command? I'm wondering if maybe your terminal is not UTF8.

Comment: BINGO! I had none in my server. Thanks! Please put it as answer and i'll accept it.